# Интерпретация итогов вычисления корреляции

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.x, arcgis

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

field = r'R:\TEST\21\221.gdb\TEST'
field_1 = 'SHAPE_Length'
field_2 = 'AREA_BU'

arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(field, (field_1, field_2))

print (np.corrcoef((arr[field_1], arr[field_2])))
```

Результат работы скрипта такой
 `[[ 1.          0.97810388] [ 0.97810388  1.        ]]`

Подскажите как правильно интерпретировать эти данные:
`Зависимость field_2 от field_1 = 1 Зависимость field_1 от field_2 = 0.97810388`

или

`Зависимость field_1 от field_1 = 1 Зависимость field_1 от field_2 = 0.97810388 Зависимость field_2 от field_2 = 1 Зависимость field_2 от field_1 = 0.97810388`

Comment: Диагональные единицы в коэффициентах Пирсона показывают корреляцию переменной с самой собой. поэтому для интерпретации вы можете вообще на них внимания не обращать. то есть, второй вариант интерпретации правильный. Это сильная положительная зависимость.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, верен второй вариант, потому что 1 - это коэффициент корреляции столбца самого с собой (диагональ), например. И относительно диагонали коэффициенты симметричны.

```
           field_1     field_2
field_1 [[ 1.          0.97810388] 
field_2  [ 0.97810388  1.        ]]
```

Или так совсем табличкой:

| Корреляция | field_1 | field_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| field_1 | 1. | 0.97810388 |
| field_2 | 0.97810388 | 1. |

Comment: Подскажите как вывести не 1 коэффициент ? через цикл ?

Comment: @Grechkin26 В смысле не печатать единички? А как вы тогда поймёте какой коэффициент к чему относится? Лучше вообще `seaborn heatmap` рисовать, если фич много и вы хотите корреляции посмотреть. Вы сначала объясните, какую задачу вы решаете, из этого нужно и решать, что делать с корреляциями.

Comment: Тестирую возможности связки arcgis и numpy. В моем случаи когда из двух  коэффициентов один это сам на себя смысл его выводить а если по итогу везде 1 то выводить не ``[1.0, 1.0]`` а просто [1.0] а если есть не 1 то выводить только ``[0.97810388]``

Comment: Ну можно так, например: `sorted(coeffs)[-2]` - этот код возьмёт второй по величине коэффициент.